# How can I read a text file of image intensity values and convert to a cv::Mat?

Tags: matlab, opencv, tracking

I am working on a project that requires reading intensity values of several images from a text file that has 3 lines of file header, followed by each image.  Each image consists of 15 lines of header followed by the intensity values that are arranged in 48 rows, where each row has 144 tab-delimited pixel values.

I have already created a .mat file to read these into Matlab and create a structure array for each image.  I'd like to use OpenCV to track features in the image sequence.

Would it make more sense to create a .cpp file that will read the text file or use OpenCV and Matlab mex files in order to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend writing C++ code to read the file directly independent of Matlab. This way, you don't have to mess with row major vs. column major ordering and all that jazz. Also, are there specs for the image format? If it turns out to be a reasonably common format, you may be able to find an off-the-self reader/library for it.

If you want the visualization and/or other image processing capabilities of Matlab, then mex file might be a reasonable approach.